# How to get a value from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have created an app where you can order things. Then I have this section/window where you can see what you have already ordered: [Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PnGC.jpg)

When you click on an order, you can see more details:
[Detailled overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St643.jpg)

But the problem is I don't get the 59 from the table from the first image. Does anyonew know how this can be done?

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class UserBestellAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Bestellung> bestellung;
    Context mContext;
    Dialog epicDialog;

    public UserBestellAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bestellung> list) {
        mContext = context;
        bestellung = list;
        epicDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_bestell, parent, false);
        UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }
    @NonNull

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      //Gesamtpreis:   holder.item_betrag.setText(String.valueOf(bestellung.get(position).getBetrag()));
      // Datum:   holder.item_datum.setText(bestellung.get(position).getDatum());
        holder.item_items.setText(bestellung.get(position).getProdukte());
        //holder.item_code.setText(bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer());
        String bestellid =bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer() + "";
        holder.item_code.setText(bestellid);
        holder.item_betrag.setText(Double.toString(bestellung.get(position).getSumme()));
        holder.item_datum.setText(bestellung.get(position).getDatum());


        holder.layout_user_bestellung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView order_overview_number = epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.order_overview_number);

                //order_overview_number.setText();
                epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview);
                epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                Button btn_order_overview_finish = (Button) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_order_overview_finish);

                btn_order_overview_finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        epicDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                epicDialog.show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()  {
        return bestellung.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView item_items, item_betrag, item_datum, item_code;
        private ConstraintLayout layout_user_bestellung;



        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            item_items = itemView.findViewById(R.id.items);
            item_betrag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.betrag);
            item_datum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datum);
            item_code = itemView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            layout_user_bestellung = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_user_bestellung);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment:

```
public class UserFragmentBestell<Textview> extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView notfound;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment_bestell, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_scroll);
        notfound = view.findViewById(R.id.user_order_notfound);
        getBestellungen();

        return view;

    }

    //Abrufen aller Bestellungen eines Nutzers aus der Datenbank
    public void getBestellungen() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("bestellungen").orderBy("bestellnummer", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                ArrayList<Bestellung> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bestellungen wurden gefunden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if(task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                    notfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Es wurde keine Bestellung gefunden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }



                                // ******LISTE WIRD ZWEIMAL AUFGERUFEN*******
                                else {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        //Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                        Bestellung best = document.toObject(Bestellung.class);
                                        list.add(best);
                                        //System.out.println(bestellung[0] + bestellung[1] + bestellung[2]);
                                    }
                                    //System.out.println("Test: " + list.get(0).toString());
                                    //System.out.println("Test: " + list.get(1).toString());
                                    listeVerarbeiten(list);
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bestellungen wurden gefunden!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Es ist ein Fehler beim Abrufen der Bestellungen aufgetreten: " + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }

    public void listeVerarbeiten(ArrayList<Bestellung> abrListe) {

        UserBestellAdapter adapter = new UserBestellAdapter(getContext(), abrListe);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like you do it for the button click. Just add a new findViewById for the TextView and set it's text. Like this:

```
// ... your code
epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview);
((TextView) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)).setText(String.valueOf(bestellung.get(position).getDatum()));
// ...your code
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
Unfortunately, it doesn't work.`order_overview_number.setText(String.valueOf(bestellung.get(position).getDatum()));` `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: That's because order_overview_number is null. Make sure you've assigned a value to it (with findViewById or View Binding).